# Is there a way to ignore the argument if it is not of a certain type/make an optional argument?

Tags: python, discord.py

So, for example, I have this code(in a cog):

```
@commands.command()
async def send_message(self, ctx, user : discord.Member = None,*, text = None)
if user and text:
  await ctx.send(user.mention + text)
elif not user and text:
  await ctx.send(text)
```

this code is supposed to send the message and mention a user if one is mentioned,
but if there is no *member* object in the first argument of the message, it just shows an error and doesn't set *text* to all the other words in the message. Is there a way for the *user* argument to be completely ignored if the correct object type is not there?

Comment: Please [edit] your code to indent it properly. Also, please clarify what you exactly want. [Use backticks (\`) to highlight parts of your code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code-spans) like `variable` and `discord.Member`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `isinstance()` to test the type of the argument.

```
if text:
    if isinstance(user, discord.Member):
        await ctx.send(user.mention + text)
    else:
        await ctx.send(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, isinstance is the right way to check the object type. But type can also be used if you are aware of the subclasses.

```
if text is not None:
    if type(user) is discord.Member:
        await ctx.send(user.mention + text)
    else:
        await ctx.send(text)
```